# Having trouble assigning to a generic delegate in C#

Tags: c#

My problem is as follows:

```
public abstract class A {}

public class B : A {
    public static IList<B> MyMethod(){ return new List<B>();}
}

public delegate IList<T> MyDelegate<T>() where T : A;



...

public static void CalledMethod<T>() where T : A{
    MyDelegate<T> del = B.MyMethod;  // This doesn't work
}
```

Can anyone explain the best way to get this to work?

Thanks for any help.

**edited** to fix example.

Comment: I think you left out too much code

Comment: You have to call it `B.MyMethod` but that still leaves you with the fact that `List<T:A>` is just not compatible with `List<B>`. Too much generics.

Comment: I think you are on the right course Henk; the error I am getting is about the signature mismatch.  Is there any reasonable way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why this will not work

```
public class C: A {}

CalledMethod<C>();
```

This means that `del` will be of type `MyDelegate<C>` which does not work with `B.MyMethod` because `C` is not a `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler what `MyMethod` is:

```
MyDelegate<T> del = B.MyMethod;
```

Comment: sorry, mistyping in my example.  In the actual code, it is that way.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done the way you are coding it, because you are attempting to make MyDelegate co-variant, but the `IList<T>` interface returned does not support variance because it can't.

`IList<B>` and `IList<A>` can't support variance either way.  Think of it this way, a `List<SalariedEmployee>` can't be completely treated like a `List<Employee>` since that would let you `Add(new HourlyEmployee)` incorrectly.